# Java 11 inline supplier with parameter

Tags: java

How to change this method:

```
   private Supplier<String> createMySupplier(Long myId) {
        return new CachingSupplier<>(
                () -> retrieveName(myId)
        );
    }
```

to inline implementation, so it would become a property in a class, not a method as it is now ?

Something like this:

```
private Supplier<String> mySupplier = () -> new CachingSupplier<>(
                    () -> retrieveName(myId)
            );
```

Comment: _to inline implementation ?_ what you mean?

Comment: What is *inline implementation*? "Inline" refers to syntactical pattern.. whereas, implementation is a word, from completely different world.

Comment: you can do `return retrieveName(myId);` but it makes it a factory of `String`, and not of `Supplier<String>`

Comment: Given that suppliers are parameterless, and your code takes a `Long myId`, what you want makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want a lambda that generates a `Supplier<String>` based on a parameter.  For that, you will need a [LongFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/LongFunction.html):

```
private LongFunction<Supplier<String>> supplierGenerator =
    myId -> new CachingSupplier<>(() -> retrieveName(myId));
```

That is rather hard to read, so I would stick with your first approach, because a reference to the createMySupplier method already *is* a LongFunction.  For instance, you can write:

```
void doStuff() {
    LongFunction<Supplier<String>> supplierGenerator = this::createMySupplier;
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
void doStuff() {
    callMethodThatNeedsSupplierGenerator(this::createMySupplier);
}
```

You may have to change `Long` to `long`.  But I’m guessing you can’t actually retrieve a name using a null ID anyway, right?